# How to store a blog post as a Markdown with React + Express + MongoDB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, markdown

I'm learning how to create a web page like a community where people go, ask, discuss and share stuff (like [dev.to](https://dev.to/)) in my personal project for learning purposes. Right now, I'm struggling with figuring out the way to store posts in my database since I want them to have images, codes, comments, likes, etc. I used Gatsby in the past and I love the way it stores Markdown files and renders to HTML, so I'm looking for the same way to do that with Express + MongoDB but seems not promising. Is there a way to accomplish that? Thank you. Any comment is appreciated to me.

Comment: Did you ever manage to find any answer to this?

Comment: No, I haven't found any suitable answer for my problem. All of the answers I got could be implemented but for read-only. So, instead of storing in database, I stored the files directly in my server, and I used parser engine to read the files. It worked but not in the way I wanted.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you basically:

1. Wrote text using Markdown
2. Stored as such in database
3. Rendered with for example [React Markdown](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown)?